# PineScript 4 - Calculate bar spread

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I need help to calculate if the close price is > or < of the 100% of the bar.
For example... if the close is > or < of the 50%, 66%, 33%, etc, of the current bar.

Im did for the 50% something like this, but is not working...

close_middle = low[0] + high[0] /2
Buy = close > close_middle

Help please! So many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about these two bool expressions

```
full = close == high
half = close > hl2
```

full will be true if it closes at the high, otherwise false, and the other will be true if close is greater than the halfway point.

Cheers and all the best to you

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bjorgum! I will try with that...